# Reading data from Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, python, django, backend

I'm using the Django framework and I'm trying to get the data from a Javascript Promise as follows:

**Js file**

```
console.log("working");
$("#username").keyup(function(event){
  let user=event.target.value
  fetch("/login/userValidation/",{
    body:JSON.stringify({username:user}),
    method:"POST"
  }).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res.json());
  });
});
```

**Py file (views.py)**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse as jresp
from django.views import View
import json

class userValidation(View):
    def post(self,req):
        data=json.loads(req.body)
        user=data['username']
        print(user)
        if(user.isalnum()):
            if(User.objects.filter(username=user)):
                print("Username not available")
                return jresp({"user_status":"Username not available, try something else"})
            else:
                print("Username Valid")
                return jresp({"user_status":"Username Valid"})
        else:
            print("Please enter alphanumeric characters only")
            return jresp({"user_status":"Please enter alphanumeric characters only"})
```

Fetch() is posting the data from the client-side to the server and the server is receiving the data just fine, as I have checked by printing out the data in the backend. However, the JsonResponse that is being returned to the client is showing **undefined** instead of the actual data - I'm not able to get the required data from the promise, using `response.json()` under the subsequent `then()` function.

Anything I'm missing out on? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine and you're on the correct path.

The call `res.json()` returns a Promise and if you chain an additional `then` call we can log the JSON data in this arrow function.

```js
console.log("working");
$("#username").keyup(function (event) {
  let user = event.target.value;
  fetch("/login/userValidation/", {
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: user }),
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((res) => {
        // return Promise
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        // log JSON data
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sir I'm adding another `then()` function  for logging the Json data like you mentioned, but I'm still getting "undefined" in the console.